# ¿Cómo creo una lista anidada?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo este código:

```
lista = [2, 0]
lista_Grande = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    lista[1] = i
    print(lista)
    lista_Grande.append(lista)
    print(lista_Grande)
```

Mi intención es que una lista que va cambiando sea agregada como elemento a un lista más grande, o sea crear una lista anidada.

El problema con el código es que me da el resultado es el siguiente:

```
[2, 0]
[[2, 0]]
[2, 1]
[[2, 1], [2, 1]]
[2, 2]
[[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
[2, 3]
[[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]        
[2, 4]
[[2, 4], [2, 4], [2, 4], [2, 4], [2, 4]]
```

Cuando lo que yo quiero es esto:

```
[2, 0]
[[2, 0]]
[2, 1]
[[2, 0], [2, 1]]
[2, 2]
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[2, 3]
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]        
[2, 4]
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Así la lista_Grande funciona como un registro histórico del proceso

Gracias por cualquier ayuda

Comment: No tengo tiempo de ver bien el código, pero puede que tu problema venga porque **las listas son mutables** por lo que puede que estés modificando la misma lista en vez de crear listas nuevas. Puedes leer [list mutable & dynamic](https://realpython.com/lessons/lists-mutable-dynamic/#:~:text=Lists%20and%20Tuples%20in%20Python&text=Many%20types%20in%20Python%20are,data%20type%20that%20is%20mutable.)

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin ayudarme, se que las lista son mutables, de hecho en otras partes del código yo agrego elementos a una lista, y no se modifican los elementos prexistentes en la misma, sigo el mismo procedimiento, pero con diferente resultado

Answer (score 0):

En la ejecución se están perdiendo datos puesto que estas sobreescribiendo `lista` (que es una lista) con una variable entera `lista[1] = i`

Por otro lado, tampoco estas haciéndolo dinámico ya que estas fijando `range(0, 5)`.

El algoritmo del problema es ir añadiendo en una lista grande, una sublista de:

```
...,
[el_primer_elemento_de_la_lista, numero_de_iteracion],
[el_primer_elemento_de_la_lista, numero_de_iteracion + 1],
...
```

Dicho eso, se puede arreglar tu programa así:

```
lista = [2, 3]
lista_Grande = []
for i in range(lista[1]+1):
    lista_Grande.append([lista[0], i])
print(lista_Grande)
```

Lo mismo, pero escrito en [comprensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lista = [2, 3]    
lista_Grande = list([lista[0], x] for x in range(lista[1]+1))
print(lista_Grande)
```

Ambos códigos retornan:

```
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: el tema esta en que yo no se como esta compuesta lista, en primer lugar lista ya es una lista anidada, que contiene varias sablistas de dos elemento, la composición de lista me la da una función que recibe los parámetros del usuario, no se con cuantas sebistas empieza ni con cuantas termina. Por ejemplo: Ejemplo 1: lista1= [[1, 3], [2, 9], [3, 5], [4, 1]] lista2 =[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 7], [4, 1]]  lista3 = [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 3]] y lista_Grande = [lista1, lista2, lista3]. Ejemplo 2: lista1 = [1, 20] lista2 = [2, 8] lista3 = [[2,3], [3, 2]] y lista _Grande =  [lista1, lista2, lista3]